# Numpy dot over of shapes (2,) (3,1) gives error but multiplication doesn't

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I'm looking for a bit clarification on broadcasting rules and numpy.dot method over multiplication factor. I have created two arrays of shape (2,) and (3,) which can be multiplied by adding a new axis (3,1 shape) but it couldn't be through np.dot method even though adding a new axis and turning into (3,1) shape. here's the below little test done.

```
x_1 = np.random.rand(2,) 
print(x_1)
x_2 = np.random.rand(3,)
print(x_2)
> [ 0.48362051  0.55892736]
> [ 0.16988562  0.09078386  0.04844093]

x_8 = np.dot(x_1, x_2[:, np.newaxis])
> ValueError: shapes (2,) and (3,1) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 3 (dim 0)

x_9 = x_1 * x_2[:, np.newaxis]
print(x_9)
> [[ 0.47231067  0.30899592]
  [ 0.17436521  0.11407352]
  [ 0.01312074  0.00858387]]

x__7 = x_1[:, np.newaxis] * x_2[:, np.newaxis]
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,1) (3,1)
```

I understand np.dot of (2,1) & (1,3) works, but why not (2,1) & (3,1) because broadcasting rule number two says, Two dimensions are compatible when one of them is 1. So if one of its dimension is 1, np.dot should work or have I understood rule number two wrong ? Also why X_9 works (multiplication) but not x_8 (np.dot), when both are same shapes.

Comment: `broadcasting` rules don't apply to `dot`.

Comment: What do you expect `dot` to do with 2 1d arrays?  Or with 2 that have been expanded to 2d?  Inner product?  Outter?

Comment: @hpaulj The equation i was working on, δ=W f(h) is trying to get inner product. A scalar value in the end. So I was working out to use on np.dot method over numpy multiplication to have better understanding and where I should use np.dot's and numpy multiplications. Any suggestions / experience to know on this ? And thank you, didn't find out in broadcasting documentation that np.dot doesn't apply to them.

Comment: ' In mathematics, the dot product or scalar product is an algebraic operation that takes two equal-length sequences of numbers (usually coordinate vectors) and returns a single number' - from wiki.  Note the `equal-length` spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.dot is for matrix-matrix multiplication (where a column vector can be considered to be a matrix with one column and a row vector as a matrix with one row). 
* (multiplication) is for scalar multiplication in the case that one of the arguments is a scalar, and broadcasting otherwise. So the broadcasting rules are not for np.dot.
x_9 works because, as stated in the broadcasting rules here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1

so your (only) dimension of x_1, (which is 2) is compatible with the last dimension of x_2 (which is 1 because you added a new dimension), and the remaining dimension is 3.